# jQuery Add a span element within a paragraph element that is being added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using jQuery DOM elements, I am trying to add a couple paragraphs to a div. This is the code that does this and it is functional:

```
$('#detail_overlay').append($('<p/>', { "class" : "detail_txt" })
  .text( $('#data_div').data('paint_name') + " detail, " + $('#data_div').data('paint_date') ))
  .append($('<p/>', { "class" : "detail_txt" })
  .text( $('#data_div').data('paint_dim' )));
```

The output looks like:

```
Freight Vessel on Puget Sound detail, 2013
40" x 26"
```

I need to make the word "detail" italicized by wrapping it in a span tag. I cannot seem to figure out how to add a span tag within a paragraph element.

Comment: Use `.html()` method instead of `.text()` then you can add html.

Comment: Yeah and I figured I could fall back on that if need be, but it would be the first time I've ever encountered a situation where it has to be be done with .html().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 + " <i>detail, </i>" +
```

and instead of wrapping it into `.text()` wrap it into `.html()`

So your code would be,

```
.html( $('#data_div').data('paint_name') + "<i> detail</i>, " + 
$('#data_div').data('paint_date') ))
```

Comment: Alright, I knew I could do this with .html(), was just hoping there was another way. Since I can't figure one out and everyone is pushing me in the .html() direction I will just go down that path.